# How to exclude tests in Geb?

Tags: selenium, groovy, integration-testing, spock, geb

I am using Geb with Spock and I'd like to introduce tests tagging. It's easily doable in Spock using a syntax:

```
runner {
  if (!System.properties.containsKey('test.include.slow')) {
    exclude Slow
  }
}
```

This would exclude all the tests annotated with `@Slow` if `test.include.slow` property is not found. Unfortunatelly putting `exclude` into `GebConfig.groovy` doesn't really do it, because there's no such method to use there.

Is there a way to use this `exclude` method with Geb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using spock, you can use @IgnoreIf at the class or method level.

Here's a good article on it: 
http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2014/06/spocklight-ignore-specifications-based.html

Since you have a system property for it, you should just be able to plug it right in:

```
@IgnoreIf({ !System.properties.containsKey("test.include.slow") })
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track but you should put that runner configuration code in `SpockConfig.groovy` and not `GebConfig.groovy` as it is Spock specific configuration.